# duplicar fila n veces de acuerdo a un correlativo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2017

Como hago una consulta en sql server de esa frorma solo es una tabla y no quiero usar procedimientos o vistas simplemente un select hay alguna forma y sin cte gracias de antemano[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Puedes intentar con `INSERT INTO tablaNombre SELECT TOP(1) * FROM tablaNombre WHERE Recepcion=001`

Comment: Llevas 2 preguntas colocando mayormente el contenido de la misma en imágenes, por favor evita dicho comportamiento, si tienes dudas recomiendo **leas [ask]**

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu tabla se haya creado de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE OtraPrueba 
   (nombre VARCHAR(255), 
    Recepcion SMALLINT, Tipo VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO OtraPrueba VALUES('Xx', 001, '4')
INSERT INTO OtraPrueba VALUES('Xx', 001, '1')
INSERT INTO OtraPrueba VALUES('Xx', 002, 'K')
INSERT INTO OtraPrueba VALUES('Xx', 002, '1')
INSERT INTO OtraPrueba VALUES('Xx', 002, '5')
```

[image: CrearTabla]

Después tienes que hacer uso de:

```
INSERT INTO OtraPrueba 
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM OtraPrueba WHERE Recepcion=001

SELECT * FROM OtraPrueba
```

El resultado será:

[image: Resultado]

> Te dejo el SQLFiddle donde lo ejecuté: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a10b4a/2